# HP-UFT external variable : Ini or Xml file?

Tags: hp-uft

I want put some variables in an external file for non-software engineer maintenance. There are two way for that :

- The old way, with a .INI file, it's look like more simple for non-dev
  maintenance.
- The new way, with an XML file.

  Someone knows the advantages of the new way (XML file) ?

Comment: advantage of xml is that if you have huge configuration you can easier manage it; you can do includes (split to many xmls) you can make structure of your settings according to specific parts of your app. If your conf is 10 lines and you are sure it will never grow - no need for xml

Comment: additionaly depends of your user audience, but its always a good idea to provide simple gui to fill those settings; values then can be saved binary to avoid user crippling settings file.

Comment: Ty for the fast answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a `property` file? XML is verbose and difficult to maintain for big projects. Property files are easy to update - non tech user can understand.

Use a property file. I have explained [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/parameterize-qtpuft-script-to-run-on-any-test-environment-using-jenkins/) on using a property file for QTP.
Sample code is available in [github](https://github.com/vinsguru/tag-qtp-jenkins-demo).

Comment: Very interesting proposition, I add your website to my favorite. If I resume the answers (Drako and you), there aren't any advantages for UFT processing. The difference between INI, XML, or properties is the structure of information.